# How to use regex inside sql - permission table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a permission table that inside it there are URLs.

for example:

```
id         permission

1         /Admin/Products/{product}/edit
2         /Admin/User/{id}
```

now when the user goes to these URL's, it's mean he will have permission:

```
/Admin/Products/56/edit
/Admin/Products/1/edit
/Admin/Products/12/edit
```

now, how can I use `regex` to this scenario?

this query should return a result:

```
SELECT * FROM `permissions` WHERE `url` LIKE '/Admin/Products/56/edit'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE url LIKE '/Admin/Products/__/edit' `

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Not applicable for product with id 101 (for example).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `like`?

```
SELECT *
FROM `permissions`
WHERE `url` LIKE '/Admin/Products/%/edit'
```

This will return all products for which the user has edit permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RLIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `permissions` 
WHERE `url` RLIKE '/Admin/Products/[[:digit:]]+/edit';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f856a30ba197eaba9252140a9b6a8f6)**